# Ways to separate logic for redux reducers which only a few state needs to be shared among all the reducers

Tags: react-redux

My current situation:
I have a message state that stores what happened to app **After** some actions (in fact nearly all actions) are fired and final state is calculated. Other than this message, the other states can be separated into different independent parts. But as I need to update message state for every action, I am stuck to put every reducing functions into one giant reducers. Is there anything I can do to avoid a giant reducer and put different reducer functions to different reducers and make each reducer control a slice of the state, while sharing a common message state?

Some minimized reducer code:

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.MOVE_CHARACTER: {
            const message = computeMoveMessage(state.maze, action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                message,
            };
        }
        case ActionTypes.END_BATTLE: {
            const message = computeEndMessage(state.maze, action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                message,
            };
        }
        case ActionTypes.CHARACTER_ATTACKS: {
            const message = computeAttackMessage(state.maze, action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                message,
            };
        }
        case ActionTypes.SAVE_FILE: {
            const message = computeSaveFileMessage(state.file, action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                message,
            };
        } 
        case ActionTypes.LOAD_FILE: {
            const message = computeLoadFileMessage(state.file, action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                message,
            };
        }  
        default:
            return state;
        }
   }
```

As you can see, `LOAD_FILE` and `SAVE_FILE` reducers are mostly independent of the other three reducers. However, as I need to update `state.message`, all 5 reducers are forced to be put in one giant `reducer.js`. Is there any workaround so that I can separate the state into `state.file` and `state.maze` while both of them share `state.message`?

Comment: Can you share your reducers code so we can understand more clearly the current state and where you want to go ?

Comment: Added some info for your reference.

Comment: Can you explain what is the role of your reducer and `message` in this reducer ? Is there a reason why you should merge `state.maze` and `state.file` together ?

Comment: The role of the reducer is, well, because I need to reduce my action and previous state to new state. (aka all reducer functions are here for now) and that's why I am putting this question to see the possibly of spliting this giant reducer to smaller ones.

Notice that state.maze and state.file does not mean there is a maze reducer and file reducer at all.

Comment: The problem is that, ALL functions need state.message (which is a string), but those need state.maze does not need state.file at all, and vice visa. If I could get rid of state.message, I can separate it into two reducers.